# How to get the name of the variable in document.write?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am having a problem getting the name of the variable in document.write

```
function func(name, birth_date) {
   this.name=name;
   this.birth_date=birth_date;
   this.atestatas=studijos;
}

function studijos(){
    var egzas=2023-func.birth_date;
    return egzas;
}

var Piotr=new func ("Piotr", 1995);
var Jonas=new func ("Jonas", 2001);
var Lukas=new func ("Lukas", 1999);
document.write (Piotr.atestatas());
document.write (Jonas.atestatas());
document.write (Lukas.atestatas());
```

If I write var `egzas=2023-func.birth_date` all I get is NaN, but if I write the name of the variable for example: `egzas=2023-Piotr.birth_date`, then I get the right result of years left till the exam. Is there a code that lets me get the value of 
`document.write (Piotr.atestatas());
 document.write (Jonas.atestatas());
 document.write (Lukas.atestatas());` 
without changing the function code to the name of each of the variables?

Comment: You should probably edit the tags to take out the unnecessary ones, such as `return` and `this`, and put in the required ones, such as which programming language this is. As far as I know, this is illegal VB.Net syntax.

Comment: Please use English names for variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the object using `this` in the studijos() function. The following code works well:

```
function func(name, birth_date) {
   this.name=name;
   this.birth_date=birth_date;
   this.atestatas=studijos;
}

function studijos(){
    var egzas=2023-this.birth_date;
    return egzas;
}

var Piotr=new func ("Piotr", 1995);
var Jonas=new func ("Jonas", 2001);
var Lukas=new func ("Lukas", 1999);
document.write (Piotr.atestatas());
document.write (Jonas.atestatas());
document.write (Lukas.atestatas());
```